# how to implement auto increment in mongodb in php

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb

I am using mongodb with php
I want my id to be autoincremented with the other fields 
I use following code but it is not running 
my code is

```
 $cnt =0;
 $count = ++$cnt;
 echo $count;
 $a =  $collection->insert(array('id'=>$count,'html' => $htmlData));
```

Please help me as soon as possible

Comment: MongoDB itself uses a Mongoid for each recor. You can use that.

Comment: First google result: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/ note that an auto increment field is bad if you don't need it, please be aware that you will most likely be better off with the `OjbectId` Edit: What do you mean by it is not running your code? What is it doing? Does it give an error? Etc

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, you're setting the `id` field to your incremented number. Based on that, I expect you will find `html`, `id`, *and* `_id` fields in your inserted document. MongoDB does uses `_id`, not `id`, to store document identifiers. If that field isn't present in the data you're inserting, the driver will create a new ObjectId (MongoId instance in PHP) and assign it to that field.

Unless you have a pressing need for incrementing identifiers, you would be better served by using an ObjectId. Having said that, in addition to the documentation Sammaye linked ([here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)), you might find the auto-increment generator class from Doctrine MongoDB ODM a helpful example (see: [here](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Id/IncrementGenerator.php)).